# How to change the font for asp.net-mvc3 WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I specify the font for an html webgrid in asp.net-mvc3?

```
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(...);                 
 }


<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid",
        headerStyle: "head",
      ...)
```

Where are these styles being created?

```
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid",  <- I can't find these styles anywhere in my mvc3 project?
        headerStyle: "head",
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: in your css
(or div#grid p i dont know what tag will be appear for grid rows when grid is rendered, you can use for example firebug and see what tag will be there )

```
div#grid span 
{
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

and if you cant find webgrid class try to write it by yourself.

Comment: But, I have no idea where the webgrid glass is being generated.

Comment: This is what is being generated: <div id="grid" class="gen"> <table class="webgrid"> – Mariah 6 mins ago

Comment: In your html find <table class="webgrid"> and look for td there if you have some rows with data there see in what tags they are.